# Strange Fortran instruction

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Learning old Fortran77-codes full of "goto-spagetti", I met with the following instruction:

```
if(condition) label1, label2, label3
```

where labels are just three numbers. Has anybody any ideas what it means?

Comment: Covered by other Qs and As hereabouts too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arithmetic if. It goes to

- label1 if the expression is negative
- label2 if the expression is 0
- label3 if the expression is positive.

Caveat: If you use it with floating point expressions, note that a result that should be 0 might be "a small number close to 0" due to rounding errors. This limits the usefulness of the arithmetic if.